# Java on Windows cant list cacerts

Tags: java

I am trying to use keytool - list to list all certs on Windows 10 in Java 8.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin>keytool -list $JAVA_HOME\lib\security\cacerts
Illegal option:  $JAVA_HOME\lib\security\cacerts
keytool -list [OPTION]...
```

I also note that :

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin>echo %JAVA_HOME% %JAVA_HOME%`

Simply echos what I typed in back to me.

I have also tried:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291\bin>keytool -list %JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts
Illegal option:  %JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts
keytool -list [OPTION]...
```

Java home is set to the JDK (not the JRE)

[image]

How can I fix this so I can list the keys?

Comment: Did you add the environment variable before or after opening the current command prompt? If you added it after, then you may need to open a new command window before it'll take effect.

Comment: Dollar signs are used in the various Linux shells, not Windows command prompt.

Comment: Should path be set to jre or jdk?

Comment: The value of JAVA_HOME is fine. It can to point either the JRE or the JDK. Depending on what you actually want to use.

Comment: Looks like the usual quoting problem.  "Program Files" has a space; unquoted space is an argument separator. Use quotes/

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: all Unix not just Linux; plus powershell but with a different (less simple) syntax. And make, although you might count that as an honorary shell. Also perl for most local vars (not envvars), and awk for fields (not other vars).

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated?

If your `PATH` variable is configured properly, you can just write: `keytool -list -cacerts` into your current cmd.

If you want to open a specific path, you need to pass the `-keystore` option and probably quote the path - also note that the `cacerts` file may reside in the `jre/lib` folder, not in the `lib`.

```
keytool -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts"
```

Comment: I cant see this working. For starters java home points to the path upto and including jre...you still need to and the remainder of the path starting at lib not jre

Comment: That's actually the way it should work  when your Java is properly installed.  The PATH variable contains one entry which points to the bin directory of your Java installation, making all the *.exe files (including keytool.exe) directly accessible in your cmd without having to write the path. The JAVA_HOME variable points to the root folder of the Java installation...

Comment: to \java or to \java\jre?

Comment: Path: `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot\bin`
JAVA_HOME:  `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot`

Comment: but keytool does not exist in jdk only jre

Comment: That's actually not true.

Comment: Might need a new question but why if cacerts is there am I getting ` javax.net.ssl.SSLException: javalang.RunTimeException: UnexpectedError: java.security.InvalidAlgoritmParameterException: the trustedAnchors parameter must be non empty` when I try to run my code